# How to add repeat same value inside array list using PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to repeat same value again inside the respective json array list with different key using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$output=array(array("0"=>1,"name"=>"raj","regno"=>12),array("0"=>2,"name"=>"raja","regno"=>15));
//echo json_encode($output);
```

The above array is giving the following output.

```
[{"0":1,"name":"raj","regno":12},{"0":2,"name":"raja","regno":15}]
```

Here I need to repeat the same value again with diferent key and the expected output format is giving below.

**expected output:**

```
[
    {"0":1,"1":"raj","name":"raj","2":12,"regno":12},
    {"0":2,"1":"raja","name":"raja","2":15,"regno":15}
]
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Question is unclear: What is the rule for the merge?(ex:why `"2":12` in the expected output) Can't you do this when retrieving the data?

Comment: Is the third supposed to be 18 as the last value?

Comment: seems more like first item is ID, second item is name value, third item is name key and name value, fourth item is regno value and fifth regno key and regno value ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_values()`](https://php.net/array_values) and the [`+` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) to merge index-based array and key-based array. This could be done inside [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map):

```
$output = array(
    array("0"=>1,"name"=>"raj","regno"=>12),
    array("0"=>2,"name"=>"raja","regno"=>15)
);

$output = array_map(function($data) {
    return $data + array_values($data);
}, $output);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Output (reformatted):

```
[
    {"0": 1, "name": "raj", "regno": 12, "1": "raj", "2": 12},
    {"0": 2, "name": "raja", "regno": 15, "1": "raja", "2": 15}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

json_encode have an option for human reading : JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

See doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

you will have the output you want